# How to add Authorization header in redirect (Spring Security)

Tags: java, redirect, spring-security

I am trying to redirect to a URL after certain checks are passed.

```java
@GetMapping("/verify")
public void verify(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setHeader("Authorization", "bearer ehxxxxxxxx");
  response.sendRedirect("/home");
}
```

But I am unable to retrieve the `Authorization` header at `JwtAuthenticationFilter`. (Skipping that code, since it works for other requests).

What am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: Can I use `*AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@GetMapping("/verify")
public void verify(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setHeader("Authorization", "bearer ehxxxxxxxx");
  RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home");
  view.forward(request, response);
}
```